# Why Windows Hello says my camera is incompatible with Windows Hello

Tags: windows, authentication, camera

I decided to use face recognition for my PC and found that the Face Recognition option is unavailable with the message **Windows Hello could not find a compatible camera**. After digging on previous posts here, I learned that Windows Hello needs to check **depth** and that is for security to make sure that a picture of the owner cannot be held against the camera to gain illegal access to the computer. Now back to my problem, the camera is **HP Truevision HD**, why is windows telling me that, is it a **driver** issue or a windows **update** issue or my camera does not have the **required infrared tech**, I just need clarifications because sites online suggest that I install a new driver, Thank you for your help.

Comment: This was the first result when I googled "HP Truevision HD Windows Hello": https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-hello-not-working/e40118af-bebd-41cc-96a2-a8fe1232b825

Comment: The laptop does not support the IR tech, am feeling inadequate, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your webcam needs to include a IR sensor for facial recognition. Without these essential components, windows hello face cannot function.